# Python Script to Web App Using Heroku and Streamlit

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications, streamlit, procfile

I am attempting to create a web app to heroku.

It says that it deploys successfully but when I try to open it I get an error saying to check the console log.

There I find the following error code:

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=name_name.herokuapp.com request_id=40cff699-28b5-4ea7-985b-c135dc8a526b fwd="174.16.132.201" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

After searching around it appears to be a problem with my procfile. I have tried switching between 'web' and 'worker' but both give me the same error (above). Other peoples procfiles look very different to mine but I don't know enough about them to know what to change.

My current procfile:

```
worker: sh setup.sh && streamlit run name_name.py
```

Comment: Could you post a reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

Sample Procfile, note it must be capital P.

The `app.py` is the script filename.

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

Comment: My script file is named app.py and Procfile has a capital P.

Comment: Use web and not worker.